# Twig variable from one loop in another doesn't work

Tags: symfony, twig

I have two loops in Twig. One is to check the stock level of a product, the other is to display some product options. I'm trying to create a variable from one loop which I can use inside the other to add a class name to a list(s).

I can't get that to work. Any help is more then welcome...

What I have is this:

```
          {% set stockLevel = '' %}
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
          {% set stockLevel = variant.stock.level %}
          {{ stockLevel }} // gives 1 0 1 1 (So all sizes except the second one are available)
         {% endfor %}

            {% for option in product.options %}
                <ul class="optionslist">
                  {% if option.values %}
                  {% for value in option.values %}


        <li class=" {% if stockLevel == 0 %}not_on_stock {% endif %}" >
          <a class="item">etc...</a>
        </li>             

                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
               </ul>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The trick is to "connect" both values. Like so:

```
{% for option in product.options %}
    {% if option.values %}

        <ul id="product_configure_option2_{{ option.id }}" data-id="{{ option.id }}">
            {% for value in option.values %}

                {% set stock = null %}
                {% for variant in product.variants **if variant.title == (option.title ~ ': ' ~ value.title)** %}
                    {% set stock = variant.stock %}
                {% endfor %}

                <li value="{{ value.id }}"{% if not stock.available %} class="not_on_stock"{% endif %}>{{ value.title }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong the way you are handling your data. Right now, event if your variable was accessible in your second **for** loop, the value of it would be the one set lastly and your script would've failed anyway.

I can suggest a bit of a hacky way, feel free to improvise or use the idea behind it.

Say, we assign an empty array:

```
{% set variantsArray = [] %}
```

Then, we will use the filter **merge** to fill it with some dummy data(that's where your first loop comes into play)

```
{% for number in 1..5 %}
    {% set variantsArray = variantsArray | merge([number]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then to be sure, we can access all the values there, we will just dump it out(that's where your second loop comes)

```
{% for index in 1..3 %}
    {{ dump(variantsArray) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The following dump generated:

```
array:5 [▼
   0 => 1
   1 => 2
   2 => 3
   3 => 4
   4 => 5
]
```

Hope you got the idea. Any suggestions are kindly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, how do you get your stock level from the variants? i think it is better to have a service function which help you get your stock level by product, the code would be cleaner :

## controller action

```
$stock_helper = $this->container->get('stockhelper_service');
$stocklevel = $stock_helper->getStockLevelByProduct($product); //getstocklevelbyproduct handle your logic and return the stock level integer.
```

pass this variable to the twig.

One variable in your twig, no loops there, clean view, understandable code in your view and action.

Comment: this solution takes few more minute of work of what you are trying to do for sure, if you have knowledge about services but it will make your life easier afterward. 2 line of code you get your stock level, if you really want to not touch your action you can create your own twig function to get the stockvalue of some product id.